# Silverlight Validation Methods

Tags: wpf, silverlight, validation

I am seeking a method to validate silverlight forms.
That could be very helpful if someone with good experireance to suggest me proper method.

I thought about validation in Binding (NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True), but in our project there are custom control and some fields setted manually in code behind.

What we need is to show tooltips when something is wrong and to have a method IsValid for a scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [DataForm](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-Rich-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-3-Introduction.aspx) control using [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), this is best practice when developing with Silverlight. You can validate using [ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx).

Comment: Bas: +1 DataAnnotations are awesome for simple validations.  But validations that involve other VMs requires a little more work.  Also, a DataForm requires a submit.  If you wanted to validate as you go, then that too requires a little more work.

Comment: DataForms do not require a submit, you can modify them to validate while typing.